# "а именно"

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки препинания пишутся после "а именно"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятыми выделяется вся конструкция, в которой присутствует "а именно" (как правило это вводное предложение), но сам союз запятыми не выделяется.
Пример: *"Хищные животные, а именно лисы, являются главным переносчиками бешенства"*.
Если после "а именно" идет перечисление, то после союза нужно ставить двоеточие.
Пример: *"Он купил угощение к Новому году. А именно: шампанское, конфеты и фрукты"*

Answer (score 0):

Надо различать пояснительную конструкцию (член предложения или целое предложение), а также случай, когда после обобщающего слова стоит «а именно» перед перечислением однородных членов.

1. Пояснительный член (выделяется запятыми):

Хищные животные, а именно лисы, являются главным переносчиками бешенства.

В самой же службе, именно в следствиях, Иван Ильич очень быстро усвоил прием отстранения от себя всех обстоятельств, не касающихся службы (Л. Толст.).

2. Пояснительное предложение (перед «а именно» ставится запятая, а после - двоеточие):

При этом необходимо учитывать одно важное обстоятельство, а именно: нельзя нарушать экологическое равновесие".

Шампанское сообщило ему расположение к разным экстренностям, а именно: он решил не ехать еще домой, а заехать к одной знакомой даме… Н. Гоголь, Шинель.

3."А именно" может открывать исчерпывающее перечисление. «перед союзом ставится запятая, а после него – двоеточие»:

На этом угольном столе поместилось вынутое из чемодана платье, а именно: панталоны под фрак, панталоны новые, панталоны серенькие.

В остальном все пока живы и здоровы, передайте привет всей нашей деревне, а именно: Козонковым, Евдокии, бригадиру Ивану, Пете-кузнецу и всем, всем.

Он купил угощение к Новому году, а именно: шампанское, конфеты и фрукты.